# Creality Ender 4 extruder problem

Tags: extruder, creality-ender-4

I cannot get my extruder to work on my Creality Ender-4 printer. I have heated the nozzle but the extruder does not move.

I tested the motor and cable on another system and they work just fine.

Could it be the board or what could it be?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your 3D printer runs [Marlin firmware](https://reprap.org/forum/read.php?415,789291). Marlin firmware default code has build in protection against extrusion below a certain temperature (usually 170°C) as defined in the [printer configuration](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/Configuration.h):

```
// *** IT IS HIGHLY RECOMMENDED TO LEAVE THIS OPTION ENABLED! ***
#define PREVENT_COLD_EXTRUSION
#define EXTRUDE_MINTEMP 170
```

Are you sure that it heats up above this temperature? Please check the connections of the thermistor and the heater cartridge.

Marlin firmware code supports disabling the cold extrusion safety measure by setting:

```
M302 S0    ; Allow extrusion at any temperature
```

(save this line in a file with extension `gcode` and load and run it from an SD card or alternatively hook up your computer over USB to the printer and use an application like Pronterface, Repetier-Host, etc. to upload the command to the printer)

If cold extrusion safety is turned off, you should try to extrude (without loading filament) to test if the extruder works.

To revert use the following code:

```
M302 S170  ; Allow extrusion above 170
```

Answer (score 2):

I change the stepper driver and that helped.

One of the stepper driver was faulty.

Comment: Jens, may I ask what stepper driver you used as a replacement for your faulty driver module? What is the chip part number, or module name?

Comment: Please mark your answer as the accepted answer, that way your question will no longer be in the unanswered list. Also, please use the [edit] link to fix errors in your answers, rather than adding the correction in the comments.